# How to use firebase database from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase Database from a `BroadcastReceiver` to fetch some data. Unfortunately the user is `null` sometimes, which means I can't use the UID the fetch data.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) { 
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if(user != null){
                        //sometimes not null
                    }else{
                        //sometimes null
                    }
                }
     });
}
```

Also `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser` is `null` sometimes. Also, i'm not running long time opertaion inside my `broadcastreceiver`. I'm talking about fetching a single opjes without any nodes under it.

How can I use Firebase database from a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The problem wasn;t the broadcastreceiver, but firebase refreshing the token. At that point the user was `null`. Something like this worked:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) { 
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user != null){
                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(this);
                    //do stuff
                }else{
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try delegating to an intent service like this

```
public class AuthenticationCheckService extends IntentService {

public AuthenticationCheckService() {
    super("AuthenticationCheckService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    //Once this code runs and its done the service stops so need to worry about long running service
    checkAuthenticationStatus();
}

private void checkAuthenticationStatus() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth)  {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            //Do stuffs
        } else {
            //Resolve to authentication activity
        }
    }
});
}
}
```

Then start the service inside the onReceive method like this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) { 
 //Method implemented below  
 checkAuthStatus(context);

}

private void checkAuthStatus(Context context) {
    Intent authCheckIntent = new Intent(context, AuthenticationCheckService.class);
    context.startService(authCheckIntent);
}
```

then remember to register the service in your manifest file

```
 <service android:name=".AuthenticationCheckService" />
```

Comment: Maybe even add [`WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService` and `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html).

Comment: This looks promising, but why would delegating to an intent service make any difference?

Comment: @RobinDijkhof See this doc from the android articles about broadcast receivers and long running tasks 

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#system_broadcasts .

I suspect there was not enough time for the firebase authlistener to finish off hence a null user object is returned at times...That was why I suggested the use of an IntentService inside the broadcast receiver

Comment: @WanClem that makes sense. However, the authstatelistener is async right? The only thing that is synchronous is adding the listener, right?

Answer (score 3):

`BroadcastReceiver` aren't meant to be used for long-running operations, try starting `IntentService` from that receiver instead. Android will finish this receiver if work takes too long. Maybe, that is the reason why the result is null sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it isn't a long running operation. I'm talking about fetching a single item based on a id. Also there a no node under this item.

Comment: Besides, it's a callback. I'm adding an object to the `stateChangListener`. Which means the code inside it is not executed within the `broadcastReceiver`

Comment: but you pass receiver's contex - receiver may be closed. You may try to block IntentService's thread until callback is fired

Comment: Use CountDownLatch - after you get some result, save it and resume thread of a service.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if you user/device is signedIn/Login to Firebase 
for more info on how to authenticate a user check **[Set up Firebase Authentication for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/)**

Comment: I'm not asking how to use firebase. As stated in my question, I got it already up and running. There is just this specific use-case i'm having trouble with.

Comment: if the user has not be authenticated,  `FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser(); ` will always return null